# How do I enable non-free packages on Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, apt

How can I enable non-free packages on Debian?  I want to install Sun's Java JDK but it's not available to me.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Open up `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and you should see lines like the following (URLs will likely vary):

```
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib
```

Simply add `non-free` to the respective URLs you wish to use, i.e.:

```
 deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
```

Running `apt-get update` will update your local repo with the package listing.

Answer (score 31):

You can also **restrict** this a little bit if you only want **some very specific packages from non-free** (firmwares for your hardware for example).

To do so, keep your `/etc/apt/sources.list` as described by @Andrew M. Then, use Apt Pinning to disable by default all non-free packages for your current release:

Create a file named `/etc/apt/preferences.d/non-free_policy` containing the following directives:

```
Explanation: Disable packages from non-free tree by default
Package: *
Pin: release o=Debian,a=stable,l=Debian,c=non-free
Pin-Priority: -1
```

Now, create another file for the specific package you want to get from non-free.
Let's assume you want to add the Intel drivers for wireless cards for instance (package *firmware-iwlwifi*).
Create a file name `/etc/apt/preferences.d/firmware-iwlwifi_nonfree` with these lines:

```
Explanation: Enable package firmware-iwlwifi from non-free tree
Package: firmware-iwlwifi
Pin: release o=Debian,a=stable,l=Debian,c=non-free
Pin-Priority: 600
```

This configuration **avoids bloating your package with these annoying non-free packages** ;)

Comment: More information about apt pinning here: https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences

Comment: What does the `o`, `a`, `l`, and `c` mean in the `Pin:` directive, and how are multiple packages added?

Comment: origin, archive, label and component. check the man page for more details https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/apt/apt_preferences.5.en.html

Answer (score 20):

An alternative way to update the package sources configuration file is to use the `apt-add-repository` command (from the `software-properties-common` package). If you want non-free package for all sources, run:

```
sudo apt-add-repository --component non-free
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer inspired by: https://askubuntu.com/a/553847/67211

Comment: This gives me an error of `apt-add-repository: not found`

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski, install the optional package `software-properties-common` to get that tool.

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS on Linux Mint (perhaps Ubuntu). After rebooting, my cinnamon desktop went missing (in the login screen, there was no option for the Cinnamon desktop) until I did `sudo apt-add-repository non-free -r; apt update; apt upgrade; reboot`. IDK what went wrong or what was going on.

Comment: As of Debian Bookworm you might need to add `non-free-firmware` too