# Unable to locate package openjdk-7-jdk

Tags: debian, apt

I am using a base edition of Debian and am trying to install Java 7 on it using this command:

```
root@server:~# apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

However, I end up getting this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-7-jdk
```

It seems like the package is not in the repository, so I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 7):

Try a quick `apt-get update` to get the latest package lists from repos, and then `apt-cache search openjdk` to check out what the latest offered version is that's available to you, if any are.

Most likely if this is a fresh base install you're going to have to go into your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and make sure you have the non-free package lists enabled, which aren't enabled by default in Debian I believe. So check this [How do I enable non-free packages on Debian?](https://serverfault.com/questions/240920/how-do-i-enable-non-free-packages-on-debian)